# Use Scanstate vs. setup command line in Windows ICD?

Tags: windows-10

I would like to add an application to a provisioning package, and found there are apparently two different ways to do so:

- Use scanstate.exe to capture an installed application
- Use the windows imaging and configuration designer (ICD) to add an installer (setup.exe) to the provisioning package. You specify the command line options to perform a silent installation, and the application will be installed during provisioning

It seems you should use the latter if the installation is quick and can be performed silently, and scanstate otherwise.

Any advice on when I should choose which option? I want to add applications like MS Office, MS Dynamics NAV, but also simpler ones e.g. Sumatra PDF. I can imagine the larger MS applications have a preferred way of provisioning.